# WebPack Referencing Externals

Tags: webpack, ionic2

I am trying to bundle an ionic project without the libs. I want to later include the bundled app in a project with those libs. Using `externals` to exclude `node_modules` I go from a 5mb `main.js` file to a 19k `main.js` file.

Here is my `webpack.config.js`-

```
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
    target: 'web',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    entry: "./src/app/main.ts",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as a resolvable extension.
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".ts", ".js"],
        modules: ["node_modules"]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            // all files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'ts-loader'
            { test: /\.ts?$/, loader: "ts-loader" }
        ]
    }
}
```

I checked the `bundle.js` file and saw stuff like this-

```
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

module.exports = require("ionic-native");

/***/ }),
```

This makes sense because it needs to provide something to the other modules, **but** this is not going to be the right path. If I needed this require to point to something like- `../../foo/modules/`- how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you need to require **abc_xyz.json** from modules.

You can do it like below.

```
let renderjson = async () => {
  const abcxyz = await import('../foo/modules/abc_xyz.json'); // path relative to bundle.js
  return abcxyz;
}
```

```
externals: ['/abc_xyz.json/', nodeExternals()]
```

Make sure the target is **node** if you're making node build. You should also define **libraryTarget** as **commonjs2**